# pass value from mdi child to parent mdi form in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to pass value from mdi child form to mdi parent form without refreshing the mdi parent form. when I open the child form from mdi parent form the code is here.

```
Product_Defination product_Defination = new Product_Defination("", "");
                using (FetchProductsDetail fetchProductsDetail = new FetchProductsDetail("ProductDefine","",_userconfig))
                {
                    fetchProductsDetail.MdiParent =  product_Defination.ParentForm;
                    fetchProductsDetail.ShowDialog(this);
                }
```

And now the code for fetching data from child form to parent form is given below:

```
         Product_id = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
Product_Defination prod_define = (Product_Defination)this.ParentForm;                
prod_define.get_productid_notifyme(Product_id);
```

Above code is giving error 'object reference not set to an instance of an object'
Rememver that i have also used this.Owner instead of this.ParentForm
Kindly Help.

Comment: If you need a reference to mdi parent form in an MDI childern, `MdiParent` property gives you the parent form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my concern is about my code. After searching all possibilities, I put my query here.